# Fading dynamic PNGs in IE 8 with jQuery

Tags: internet-explorer-8, png, iepngfix

I've found a number of posts about hacks for fixing IE8's PNG problem, but I can't seem to adapt any of them to my scenario.

I have four PNGs that are generated dynamically using $.load(). They fade in and out, and then another four PNGs are generated and do the same thing.

In IE8 the semi-transparent parts of the images have black backgrounds.

Is there a way I could run an alpha filter on individual PNGs when they are loaded instead of upfront when the DOM is ready?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `AlphaImageLoader` filter (not `<img src="..." />`) to display the image.
Even in IE 8, this is necessary to get the filters to play together.

Comment: So I have to set the image as a background to the div?